# 404 on inner pages in subfolder WP installations (htaccess issue)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have weird problem concerning .htaccess files and 404 errors on inner pages in subfolders. Happened without any changes yesterday.

I have WP installations on root domain and subfolders us domain.com/es/ and domain.com/fr/. Permalink structure was %postname% in all these 3 installations working with no problems before. For some reason after one night I woke up with all inner pages in subfolder websites fr and es throwing 404 errors.

After multiple troubleshooting, restarting servers, web servers, backups and so on, some progress was made. When I change .htaccess file in a root website with plain (default) permalinks. Basically empty .htaccess file. Then pages in subfolder websites started showing again. If I change root .htaccess file to %postname& permalinks subfolder pages broke again. I guess somehow root .htaccess file catches subfolder urls and rewrites them. Then I have added a line to the root .htaccess file to exclude fr and es folders

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(fr|es) [NC]
```

This solves a problem partially. Now subfolder website pages works fine, but the root website with permalink structure postname has plenty of broken links. The weird part that not all, but just a part of links are broken on the root website. They even do not load a custom 404 error page, simply server side 404 that resource is not found. If I change it to default links, the same page works ok, but in this case all my external backlinks will be broken. What else I could try?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It might fit better on superuser, serverfault, or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

An issue solved modifying .htaccess file line as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/.*
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(es) [NC]
```

to prevent overwriting subfolder links.